# What is better way of referencing a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I just am a bit confused regarding what is right and wrong or rather what is the recommeded practice.

I have a class file A.cs which contains an abstract class.

I want other classes which would be located in other Dlls to reference to this class.

Hence what is the recommended practice?

Do i create a dll which contains this class and other dll's would reference this dll.

Or do i include this class file in every dll so that references are set correct (considering all dll projects reference this cs file from same location)

What is the recommended practice? What are pros and cons of same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your Object Orientated design principles. SOLID and DRY.

Write it once and reuse it.

As for where the code resides i.e. in which assembly, it's really down to how you organise your code. Does this piece of code need to be used only by code in this assembly? Does it need to be shared with others?

Comment: Yes.. I Get your point here.. Using an assembly i could hide the implementation..  Now my question would be for just one file should i be creating an assembly which could be referenced?

Comment: try to describe to me what your code does and why you would seperate it into different assemblies?

Comment: public abstract class A
{
abstract void PrepareData()
}

//Assembly 1 
class B:A
{
public override PrepareData()
}
//Assembly 2 
class C:A
{
public override PrepareData()
}

Comment: yes...but other than preparing data what are your classes actually doing? what is their business function ? Are they all functionally similar?